# Storing user authentication info on front-end

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-frontend

I am relatively new to web development and I have no idea how to securely store the user information on the front-end of application. My problem is really an issue of extracting the data using client-side javascript from the server response.

All I know how to do is to retrieve the user data via templates like EJS like so:

```
<a id="user_id" value="<%=user._id%>" ></a>
```

but there has to be a better way than that? And I get the feeling that putting the user information into the DOM is a bad idea, why not put into WebDB or IndexedDB?

Should I do it like so?:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('user_id', '<%=user._id%>');
```

the problem is that this doesn't actually retrieve the data:

[image]

So perhaps I should ask the question - how can I get the data from a server response in the head of the html?

Answer (score 2):

Well, once the user is logged in, I think it is ok to show the user his/her username, just not the password.

I would go with `localStorage` for this:

```
window.localStorage.username = 'theboss';
document.getElementById('user_id').value = window.localStorage.username;
```

[Documentation for localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, upon a successful login, a cookie is set with a UID that uniquely identifies requests made by that user. Some backends do this automatically (just Google jsessionid), and map that id to a set of variables you have saved for that client (commonly called Session Scoped variables).

Needing to add this to every form would be a terribly inefficient process. Use a cookie instead.